# Spring Boot Gradle plugin - live reload of resources with multi-module project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am having problems getting live reload of static resources to work with a gradle multi-module project.

Here is my simplified project structure:

`project
 - application
   - src/main/java/com/mypackage/MyApplication.java
 - web
   - src/main/resources/index.html`

If I am running the spring boot gradle plugin `bootRun` task to launch my application in place, via the command line, the live reload of static resources within `web` resources does not get picked up.

Now I know if the spring boot application were to exist in web also, the live reload would work.

My two questions are:

1. When running the application in place with `bootRun` and a multi-module structure, does it build the classpath from the dependency modules `build/classes` or use the `lib/mydependency.jar`?
2. Is there a way to configure the plugin to consider peer modules resources for live reloading?